# Remove banner.data block by layout file

Tags: magento2, cms-block, promotional-banner

I need to remove the block from layout file using below code,

```
<referenceBlock name="banner.data" remove="true" />
```

Because there is no way to disable Magento banners in admin, however, this can be accomplished via layout.

I am not getting in which module and which file I need to add this code.
Please suggest path and file achieve this thing.

As shown below
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Do have sample data OR you installed any extension for banner?

Comment: no extension, Magento core banners.

Comment: Actually, we are getting an error on this URL www.example.com/customer/section/load/?sections=cart&update_section_id=false&_=1561625368238. so as I am not using any block on my pages so I want disable these block

Comment: Is it in the console log?

Answer (score 0):

Copy default.xml from `vendor/magento/module-theme` into your Custom Theme Folder. like this one,

> app\design\frontend\Package_name\themename\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml

and add this line in `defualt.xml`

```
       <referenceBlock name="banner.data" remove="true" />
```

If not resolved it then please find `referenceBlock` or `referenceContainer` name to display it.